# how to change selected list item background, android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have two `ListView`'s in my `Activity`, when i select one from first `List` data will reflected to other list. I have done this part, its working fine for me. But I am struggling to change the background for selected item in first `List`, how can i do this?

Comment: post the code you have now and it will make it easier for people to answer.  If you are using custom adapters for the lists it should be an easy fix.

Comment: paste ur code. especially the onItemClick func and all

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by below  -

Set the `android:listSelector="@drawable/selection"` to your ListView's xml attribute. And, in your `selection.xml` contains the selector which will hold the change when you select any item from listview.

**selection.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/android_green" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white_alpha" />
</selector>
```

Have a look at [this](http://android-journey.blogspot.in/2009/12/android-selectors.html) also.

Comment: This allows for only one list selection at a time.  How to select multiple list items?

Answer (score 0):

Just set in your main layout of list item view

```
style="?attr/SelectableItemBackground"
```