# How to change the background of the list item which is selected in android

Tags: android, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to change selected list item background, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981366/how-to-change-selected-list-item-background-android)

In android tablets in the settings screen, the background of the listitem from the list changes until user makes the next selection, Which is standard way of getting that feature to work. Till now i used a boolean for the item which is selected and i was refreshing the list to reflect the changes after each click, i dont this, this is the right approach?

Comment: That answer dosent seem to be the appropriate one, its the normal selector for the list, once user makes the selection the background changes as a button, i want something like a check box, did u get what im trying to say

Comment: Yes. you need to use single choice listview type along with the selector.

Comment: please chech this link it may help

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11981466/1838457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use the following process . It works fine.

   Write a Global bean that get the postion of the selected item from the list.

     public class Global {      
        public static int mListPosition = 0; 

        public static int getListPosition() {
                return mListPosition;
            }    
        public static void setListPosition(int mListPosition) {
                Global.mListPosition = mListPosition;
            }   

        }

from List onClickListener set the position into the global bean


mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Global.setListPosition(arg2);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
        });



in the adapter 

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.details_retailer_list_row, null);

                mHolder = new ViewHolder();
                v.setTag(mHolder);

                mHolder.mDetailsRetailerLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.details_cart_retailer_row_layout);
                mHolder.mDetailsRetailer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailsRetailerRow);

            }
            else {
                mHolder =  (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }           


            final CartDetailsRetailerBean mDetailsRetailerBean = mItems.get(position);
            if (position == Global.getListPosition()) {
                mHolder.mDetailsRetailerLayout
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_white);
            } else {
                mHolder.mDetailsRetailerLayout
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_red);
            }

            if(mDetailsRetailerBean != null){

                Log.i("Global Position", ""+Global.getListPosition());



                mHolder.mDetailsRetailer.setText(mDetailsRetailerBean.getRetailerName());

            }

            return v;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            public LinearLayout mDetailsRetailerLayout;
            public TextView mDetailsRetailer;

        }


Please apply it . I think it will work fine.
```

Comment: Thanks.. even simple things works sometime